# Fixing error PaginationLaravel 10 Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

When I use searching feature, I got message "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist".

How to fix it?

[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfXXy.png)

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\PackingModel;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class PackingController extends Controller
{
    // method untuk tampil data packing
    public function packingtampil()
    {
        $datapacking = PackingModel::orderby('id_packing', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(5);

        return view('halaman/view_packing', ['packing' => $datapacking]);
    }
}
```

and this is my view

[image: blade file]

When I use searching feature

[image: click search]

I got this message

[image: error message]

How to fix it so I can use pagination

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solutions.
When I write in read data function

in Controller
**Read Data**

$datapacking = PackingModel::orderby('id_packing', 'ASC') ->paginate(5);

I should use the same paginate instead of using get in method search

**Search**

$datapacking = PackingModel::where('varian', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%') ->paginate(5);